# Django backend with a javascript frontend - best practices

Tags: javascript, django, angular

I stumbled upon google's material design web components ("https://material.io/") and would like to implement it in my projects. The only problem is that I've never used a javascript frontend before.

Note: Google's Material Design is the successor of Material Design Lite.

I received a recommendation to learn angular and implement Google's material design components through angular and have my frontend (angular) communicate with my backend (django) through an API.

1- Is this really the best way to proceed if only the web components are needed? Can we not just import the CSS and JS like we did with bootstrap and use Django/jinja to render views?

2- It seems like node.js / NPM is required to use angular and Google's material design, however, is that just during development? Or will we face complications when trying to deploy a django backend and javascript front end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly separate your frontend and backend, but I don't think that's necessary in this case. You can definitely import your needed JS and CSS without separating the two, (just make sure that you have them in your base template so that they're accessible to all pages). All you need is a CDN. If you want to use raw SCSS as mentioned in the webpage you linked, you can always use Django scss https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor

Onto your second question. Node.js is essentially a platform so that Javascript can run on a server as a backend , as opposed to in a browser. Angular is a frontend framework (just like Django is for python). You don't need node.js to use angular.

NPM (node package manager) is a javascript package manager for node.js, just like pip is a package manager for python. It's not necessary if you're not using node.js.

I don't see anything that would suggest that splitting frontend and backend is necessary for using material design, so you should definitely be either to do so either way. Entirely up to you.